# Java - Eclipse - How to force the application to run only one main?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, program-entry-point

I have a client application (project) in Eclipse JavaEE. Whenever I choose to run the project, multiple mains will appear.

My question is: Is there any method that we can force the project to call only one specific main whenever I run the project?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question.  I don't know what you mean by "multiple mains"

Comment: @TrippKinetics: Any number of classes can have a `main`, and Java needs to know which one to call in order to "run the project". The question is how to set one of them as the entry point, so the others basically get ignored.

Comment: Why do you have multiple mains if you only want to call one of them?

Comment: @Ironcache: Sometimes it's for testing. (You "run" a class to test it, rather than having separate tests.) Sometimes you have a bunch of sub-applications you're stitching together, and the entry point is a menu letting you decide which one to run.

Comment: @cHao can't really use those other meetings for testing if you're "forcing the project to call only one specific main whenever the project is run" though.

Comment: @Ironcache: Sure you can. Copy the class anywhere, like into (or from!) another project, and `main` inherently goes with it. Or, maybe the entry point is a test too, and runs all the other `main`s. Point being, there are entirely valid reasons to have multiple `main`s.

Comment: @cHao The question was never if it is valid to have multiple mains.  I don't see how that was gleaned from my comments or the question.  My question was, why would you want to **force running just one of those mains**?  We are on the same page about it being valid to have multiple mains...

Comment: @Ironcache: There are also entirely valid reasons for wanting to set one and only one of them as the entry point for a given project. Doesn't mean the others will never get called.

Comment: @cHao In your development environment, there really isn't.  A main is an entry point for Java.  Hiding those entry points means that you don't need the entry point at all (so you might as well just not have the entry point).  You mention both testing and sub-applications as good examples outlining this.  Testing requires you to run the main, so this is out.  Sub-applications do not rely on having other mains, and why would you disable direct access to the main you're trying to run in favor of going through your application so that you can access it... what is gained from this paradigm?

Comment: In short, if you're going to use a main method by reference only and are trying to **enforce** that it is not directly usable, then it is no different than if you were to treat it like any other static function that accepted a `String[]` argument.  It is meaningless as a main method.

Comment: As a closing point (to avoid bringing this into an extended discussion), I would say that I agree with you that just because a project doesn't care about a main doesn't mean that a main cannot be useful (IE: for external tools).  But I do not see what benefit is gained from *enforcing* that that main is not callable.  No IDE I know of allows this.

Comment: @Ironcache: I'm reading "there really isn't [a reason]" means "i don't like the ones there are", since i've already given two. The latter is fine. The former has been proven false by counterexample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170808/discussion-between-ironcache-and-chao).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running the application from within Eclipse itself, then you will need to setup a run configuration pointing to the main class you want.

The documentation for creating a run configuration can be found here:

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm?cp=1_3_6_3

*"The Main tab defines the class to be launched. Enter the name of the project containing the class to launch in the project field, and the fully qualified name of the main class in the Main class field. Check the Stop in main checkbox if you want the program to stop in the main method whenever the program is launched in debug mode.
Note:  You do not have to specify a project, but doing so allows a default classpath, source lookup path, and JRE to be chosen."*

If you are exporting your application to a .jar file, then you will want to specify the main class inside the manifest file. Instructions to do that can be found here:

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-35.htm

The main class entry in the manifest file should look like:

```
Main-Class: classname
```

For example:

```
Main-Class: somepackage.SomeClass
```

Comment: You should copy the relevant part of the link (for the manifest stuff at least instead of just providing a link. This way, SO will keep the info even if the link expire.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the main class that you want to run inside the **Run Configuration**.
So when you will run this configuration, it will only start this main.

Comment: Is there a way that I can export the main file out of the desktop so the user can just click on to run the application? The main file is the GUI login system.

Comment: @Username00097 you will want to export your project to a .jar, and then in the manifest file specify the main class.

Comment: Maybe even wrap it into an executable file (.exe) using Launch4J or something alike

Answer (score 1):

Based on your feedback to answers, it seems like you're looking to create a runnable jar.

From Eclipse:

- Right Click Project
- Run As
- Run Configurations
- Create New, reference your project name and main class.

  - If you already have a launch config defined you can use that instead of creating a new one.
- Apply + Close
- Right Click Project
- Export
- Java > Runnable Jar
- Choose the run config you just created, choose where to export it.

From here, the jar will automatically run with the launch config you gave it.  To run it from the command line:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar [... command line args ...]
```

(If you double-click it, it will also likely do what you want, if it's a GUI application).

This will use the main you defined in your run config.